# Not able to select the value from the pop-up which is similiar like dropdown -box

Tags: java, html, css, xpath, selenium

I have to select field which is similar like dropdown-box but not actual dropdown-box. The select field shows value in pop-up which contains values and sub-values, I need to select values.

**Facing issues :**

Not able to identify the object and unable to select the value from the field.

I have tried for cssSelector to identify object : "*div[class='mailval'][title='Breast > Both']*". It is not working.

**Following is the HTML Code :**

```
<div class="rowDiv ">
   <label for="bodypart">Body Part</label>
   <div id="bodypart_box_1">
       <div style="position:absolute;left:185px;z-index: 20">
           <ul class="parent">
               <li>
                   <div id="main" class="mailval">events=Object { click=[1]}handle=function()
                       <input id="bodypart_1" class="bodypart" type="text" onfocus="if($(this).hasClass('disabled')){$(this).blur();}" readonly="readonly" value="Select One" name="bodypart_1" title="">
                       <input id="actualBodypart_1" type="hidden" value="Breast" name="actualBodypart_1">
                   </div>
                   <ul id="bodyPartList_1" class="top sub bodyPartList" style="display: none;">olddisplay="block"
                       <li>
                           <div class="mailval fly" title="Breast" originaltitle="Breast">Breast</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                           <ul>
                               <li>
                                   <div class="mailval" title="Breast > Both" originaltitle="Breast > NULL > Both">Both</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <div class="mailval" title="Breast > Left" originaltitle="Breast > NULL > Left">Left</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                               </li>
                               <li>
                                   <div class="mailval" title="Breast > Right" originaltitle="Breast > NULL > Right">Right</div>events=Object { click=[1], mouseover=[1]}handle=function()
                               </li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
           </ul>
           <div style="clear:both"></div>
       </div>
       <p id="bodypart-error" class="errorMessage ml161px pa ie7ErrorFix" style="top:140px !important"></p>
   </div>
```

Comment: how is this a java question??

Comment: I need to select the value in my selenium using java.

Comment: then add the relevant java code; otherwise it's an html, css question

Comment: I am using Java not Javascipt.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what exactly? Throws what errors? What does it do vs what doesn't it do? Does it fail silently? Blow up the computer? Context is useful.

Comment: Unable to identify the element when I use this xpath : "div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval"

Comment: @Arran :  I have used xpath as given by Amuth003 : "#bodyPartList_1 > div > div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval". My Test Case shows Pass, but in the select dropdown it doesn't show selected. Can yhou please tell me how to use Context?

Comment: @user2943890, that isn't an XPath, it's a CSS selector. Using that CSS selector and your sample HTML, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The right way of using a class attribute in a selector is,it should be **preceded by "."**

your selector can be rewritten as follows,

```
div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval
```

you can try this selector as well, an **id** attribute should be **preceded by "#"**

```
#bodyPartList_1 > div div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval
```

[refer this to learn more about selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Writing_efficient_CSS)

**EDIT :**
As per your html, the popup only appears when hovered over or clicked. This action can be performed using `JavascriptExecuter`,

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("$('#bodyPartList_1 > .mailval.fly').click();");
```

Now the popup will be displayed, you just have to select the desired value...

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval"))).click();
```

Comment: I have used the cssSelector = #bodyPartList_1 > div > div[title='Breast > Both'].mailval. 

It is showing me error as " Unable to locate element:".


Could you please help me out for identifying and selecting the object.

Comment: Even I have tried for the xpath ="//*[@id='bodyPartList_1']/li[1]/div" . Element is getting identify but showing error : "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with...".

How to identify the object when it is not visible?

Comment: WebElement el = Driver.findElement(By.xpath(OR.getProperty(Object)));
  >Actions builder = new Actions( Driver );
  >builder.moveToElement( el ).click( el ).perform();